# compare values in multicurrency SF instance

Tags: force.com, formula, workflow

In a workflow rule, I want to see if a currency field (10, 2) is > 0. This compiles but doesn't trigger the rule. Help?
*** I THINK IT'S NOT WORKING BECAUSE I HAVE A MULTICURRENCY ORG***

```
    (amount__c > 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
or (
    (isBlank(Total_ACH_Amount__c)), 
    (Total_ACH_Amount__c > 0) 
    )
```

It looks like a paranthesis was not closed properly.

**EDIT: Other probable solutions I could think of -**

Perhaps you can try adding the Currency Iso code for each of your currencies along with the validation rule to see if SF will respect that?
So assuming you have USD and CAD, it will become (please check syntax):

```
OR(
      AND( ISPICKVAL (CurrencyIsoCode , "USD"),
                 (isBlank(Total_ACH_Amount__c)), 
                  (Total_ACH_Amount__c > 0) ,
      AND( ISPICKVAL (CurrencyIsoCode , "CAD"),
                 (isBlank(Total_ACH_Amount__c)), 
                  (Total_ACH_Amount__c > 0)))
```

Else you can trying this method of using a trigger and maintaining another field by converting the amounts into USD and using that field in your validation rule which is described here:
http://www.sfcnmore.com/index.php/2009/01/sfc-multi-currency-improvement/

Or can you use a formula field and copy the numeric value of the amount field and then have a validation rule on the formula field.

Comment: nope.... that was not the cause either

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using AND and OR into the rules and formulas? It's so confusing to write and read. Instead, you can use `&&` for AND and `||` for OR. It's so much easier and more readable.

Also I think you should be using `ISNULL` rather than `ISBLANK` which is used for text fields. In this case your rule will be:

```
ISNULL(Amount__c) || (Amount__c > 0)
```

Comment: 3 things. I'm using and() and Or() notation because that's  the SF syntax for formulas, and how my admins learned to read it. Second, from SF: "ISBLANK has the same functionality as ISNULL, but also supports text fields. Salesforce will continue to support ISNULL, so you do not need to change any existing formulas." Third, though your suggestion works for normal single currency orgs,  your suggestion does not work for MULTICURRENCY.